# How can I wait until pageViewer Swipe finsih in robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have pageViewer and I have Tabs like (Department,Employee)

```
I am now using the following code 

solo.clickOnText("Employee");
solo.sleep(2000);
```

to wait until the pageViewer changing of fragment to the Employee Fragment , is there more efficient way to do that, so I will not just use a random time ?

Comment: why do you want to wait after clicking on employee?

Answer (score 1):

```
solo.clickOnText("Employee");
assertTrue(solo.waitForText("Some text that you know is only on the employee tab"));
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems that ("Some text that you know is only on the employee tab") is detected by solo even if I am in another tab !? did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

> solo.waitForText("string");

has an default timeout of 5 seconds

check [here](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html#waitForText%28java.lang.String%29) what type of wait is more suitable for your test